# SQL - How to get the name of an item that has the highest returned max average?

Tags: sql

In my database, I am recording the projected net profit per hour that an item in a store might make, sampled daily. For example, a grocery store on day 1 might make $100 per hour selling apples and $50 selling oranges. On day 2 the grocery store is sampled as making $101 per hour selling apples and $57 selling oranges. In a sql query, I want to return which item has the highest average profit per hour.

My database has a table called "saved_data" that has four columns: item(for item name), category(this will have "grocery" marked for both the items apple and orange), net_profit(for the sampled net profit per hour on a given day), and date(date sampled).

I found that I could get the highest average profit per hour using this query:

```
SELECT MAX(avg_net_profit) FROM (SELECT AVG(net_profit) AS avg_net_profit FROM saved_data GROUP BY item)
```

But I'm unsure as to how to get the item name. For the example above: I need to return "apple", since its average profit per hour is the highest.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use "select Top 1" and update your query as below :

```
SELECT TOP 1
    item,
    AVG(net_profit) AS avg_net_profit
FROM
    saved_data
GROUP BY
    item
ORDER BY
    AVG(net_profit) DESC;
```